# C# video player that supports streaming?

Tags: c#, video-streaming

I want to add a video player in my Windows Form that would be able to stream videos (flv) from internet (web-server). So far i've tried Microsoft Windows Media Player and it's working but I don't like it because of its lags and bugs and etc.

So are there any other video players that can be easily embedded in a Windows Form and that support video streaming? *(by streaming I don't mean something like live TV streaming, but just downloading (buffering) and playing at the same time the video)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can embed [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) as an ActiveX component?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Flash ActiveX control which (I expect) would handle these natively.